# What is the difference between a dialog being dismissed or canceled in Android?

Tags: android

Like the title says, what is the difference between a dialog being dismissed or canceled in Android?

Answer (score 217):

Typically, a dialog is dismissed when its job is finished and it is being removed from the screen.  A dialog is canceled when the user wants to escape the dialog and presses the Back button.

For example, you have a standard Yes/No dialog on the screen.  If the user clicks No, then the dialog is dismissed and the value for No is returned to the caller.  If instead of choosing Yes or No, the user clicks Back to escape the dialog rather than make a choice then the dialog is canceled and no value is returned to the caller.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm trying to set what happens if the user pushes the cancel button on a datepicker. First I tried using a dismiss listener, and that worked, but also happened if the user chose a time. Then I tried a cancel listener, and it never went off, even if I pushed cancel. Do you know what I should do?

Comment: If you're using a DatePickerDialog, you should use an OnDateSetListener to get notified when the date changes.  If someone clicks the cancel button ... then it won't get called and the dialog will go away on its own.  For normal uses of the DatePickerDialog, you don't need to set other listeners.

Comment: FYI, the back button triggers both the cancel listener and the dismiss listener.

Comment: What if i call cancel() instead of dismiss()

Answer (score 34):

`dismiss` is something you have to explicitly call in your code, usually to respond to a click event on a button in your `Dialog`.  If you prefer, you can call `dismissDialog` in the `Activity`, which will in turn call `dismiss` on the `Dialog`.

The `cancel` method only executes when it is explicitly called in your code, or when the user presses the BACK button when your cancelable `Dialog` is open (as @Lee noted).

If you are using a `DatePicker`, then all of this is still the case.  As @Lee said, `DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener` just detects when the user has chosen a date from the `DatePicker`.

The [Android Developer Reference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#DismissingADialog) provides more info on `Dialog`s.

Comment: You can also call the `cancel` method. There are two different listeners for dimissing and canceling.

Answer (score 32):

**`Dismiss`** Calling the dismiss removes the dialog from the screen. This method can be
invoked safely from any thread. Note that you should not override this method to do cleanup when the dialog is dismissed, instead implement that in *onStop*.

**`Cancel`** Calling the cancel, cancels the dialog. This is essentially the same as calling *dismiss()*, but it will also call your *DialogInterface.OnCancelListener*, if registered.

**`Hide`** This method hides the dialog, but do not dismiss it.

[image]

And for more see [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog)

Comment: cancel and dismiss both have callbacks: 
Cancel   -> setOnCancelListener;
Dismiss -> setOnDismissListener;

Comment: @ВладиславШестернин absolutely and that's not a difference

Answer (score 9):

The difference is all about returning the value to the caller function.

`dialog.cancel()` will normally be called when the user hits the back button rather than selecting the choices that alert dialog offers like **OK/Dismiss** and return null/no value to the caller. While

`dialog.dismiss()` is normally called when the user selects from the choices that alert dialog offers like hitting the **Dismiss** button on the dialog will dismiss the dialog and will return the non-null corresponding value to the caller. That's it.

Answer (score 5):

Giving this example

```
val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this@MainActivity)
    .setTitle("Title")
    .setMessage("Message")
    .setPositiveButton("Dismiss") { dialog, _ ->
        dialog.dismiss()
    }.setNegativeButton("Cancel") { dialog, _ ->
        dialog.cancel()
    }.create()

dialog.setOnDismissListener {
    Log.i("TAG", "onDismissListener")
}
dialog.setOnCancelListener {
    Log.i("TAG", "onCancelListener")
}
dialog.show()
```

When click Dismiss button

```
onDismissListener
```

When click Cancel button

```
onCancelListener
onDismissListener
```

When system Back button

```
onCancelListener
onDismissListener
```