# Leaked windows error with progress dialog android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I have a problem showing a `progress dialog` with an `AsyncTask`:

```
Activity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{8cee959 V.E...... R......D 0,0-1026,252} that was originally added here
```

**This is my Async Task:**

```
public class MyClientTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog = null;

    private Context mContext;

    MyClientTask(Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Working ...");
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        try {
            wait(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (progressDialog != null) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            progressDialog = null;
        }

    }
}
```

**And this is my activity:**

```
public class ConnectionActivity extends Activity {

    final private Context mContext = this;
    private Button buttonConnect;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R .layout.activity_socketconnection);

        buttonConnect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonConnect);

        buttonConnect.setOnClickListener(getConnectOncOnClickListener());
    }

    private OnClickListener getConnectOncOnClickListener() {
        return new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MyClientTask myClientTask = new MyClientTask(mContext);
                try {

                        myClientTask.execute();
                        myClientTask.get();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        };
    }

}
```

I searched the solution, but it doesn't work anyway

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android activity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.phonewindow$decorview Issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12000940/android-activity-has-leaked-window-com-android-internal-policy-impl-phonewindow)

Comment: @Tigger I read it, but it's not my problem.. that solution doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of hints:

1. Keep the reference to the `ProgressDialog` in your activity and add public methods to show/hide it;
2. Use a `WeakReference<Context>` in your `AsyncTask` to let the garbage collector do it's job;
3. Get rid of the `myClientTask.get()` that blocks the UI thread.

Comment: I tried to do like you suggest, but it doesn't work the error is the same..

Comment: Could it be, that you start a new AsyncTask before the previous one has finished?

Comment: No, I never started another one.. So I can't understand why I have this problem

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when you are finishing the activity without calling dismiss() or hiding the dialog first. I suggest you to rework your code a bit, creating the actual ProgressDialog in your Activity then storing a reference to it. In your onDestroy(), as a precaution check if it is not null and showing, then dismiss() it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is calling wait() in background. Please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26590542/java-lang-illegalmonitorstateexception-object-not-locked-by-thread-before-wait).

Sample:

```
 private Object lock = new Object();

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        synchronized(lock) {
            try {
                lock.wait(5000);
                //  Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use progressDialog.cancel(); instead of progressDialog.dismiss();

you can find difference b/w them here:

[What is the difference between a dialog being dismissed or canceled in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125647/what-is-the-difference-between-a-dialog-being-dismissed-or-canceled-in-android)